# is_staff field is not showing in Django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-admin, django-custom-user

is_staff is defined as boolean field but its checkbox is not visible in the admin page. But is_admin is visible and it can be changed.

I can't able to make changes to that field using views.py

```
class Users(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    objects = UserManager()
    mobile_no = models.IntegerField(_('MobNumber'), null=True, blank=True,unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('Email'), max_length=75, null=False, blank=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('FirstName'), max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('LastName'), max_length=70, null=True, blank=True)
    role = models.CharField(_('Role'), max_length=70, null=True, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(_('Location'), max_length=70, null=True, blank=True)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(_('DateTime'), auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)
    activated = models.BooleanField(_('Activated'), default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(_('is_admin'), default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('is_staff'), default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.mobile_no)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.mobile_no)

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin


    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return self.is_admin

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'mobile_no'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['role']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the User admin in admin.py by importing and inheriting from it. Here's an example:

```
# admin.py

from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    model = Users
    list_display = ('mobile_no', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'role', 'location')
    fieldsets = (
        (('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name',)}),
        (('Permissions'), {'fields': ('activated', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'groups')}),
        (('Important dates'), {'fields': ('date_time', 'last_login')}),
    )
    class Meta:
        model = User

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Comment: ERRORS:
<class 'CustomAcco.admin.UserAdmin'>: (admin.E033) The value of 'ordering[0]' refers to 'username', which is not an attribute of 'CustomAcco.Users'.
<class 'CustomAcco.admin.UserAdmin'>: (admin.E116) The value of 'list_filter[0]' refers to 'is_staff', which does not refer to a Field.
<class 'CustomAcco.admin.UserAdmin'>: (admin.E116) The value of 'list_filter[2]' refers to 'is_active', which does not refer to a Field.

Comment: @VA splash - In the admin remove username, change is_active to activated, and I'm not sure why it's not picking up is_staff, but you can remove it for now, see if it works, and then debug from there. Ah and just realized your model is named Users not User. See above... but I would just call your model User.

Comment: It worked when I changed is_staff to some other field name. Django may have default is_staff.